# An 8255 IC is interfaced to 8086 microprocessor

Tags: microprocessors, 8085

An 8255 IC is interfaced to 8086 microprocessor .Assume the address of 8255 PORT B to be 0091H, Write down the addresses of Control PORT, PORT A and PORT C?
I am confused with the above question .Please help guys.

Comment: Confused how? Look at the 8255 docs for port layouts and use math.

Answer (score 1):

By using the following [pdf](https://edutechlearners.com/download/MP/8255%20&%20IO%20Interfacing.pdf) content :

if PORT B is 0091H

then

PORT C is 0093H and Control PORT is 0095H

Comment: Inform me if any trouble.

Comment: Thank Billa, could you please explain how?

Comment: @AayushGupta How what? Look at the 8255 data sheet.

Comment: @AayushGupta Please open the link that i gave you, it is a pdf file. Read page no. 19 and 20 , it is there. Good to hear it helped, i think you are new to stack please accept and upvote the answer let it help some one with similar doubt in future.

Comment: @AayushGupta i think you are new to stack, please respond to every reply you receive. Because behind every reply there is lot of time and effort. You must value them. Accept and upvote if answer found useful.